# How to stop multiple UILongPressGesture's from happening?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have two view's that have long press gestures on screen. The long press action in the began state adds a child view controller.

However, if I press and hold both views at the same time, I load two child view controllers on top of one another.

Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: Use the gesture recognizer delegate methods to prevent them from both recognizing simultaneously.

Comment: Or use `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` so that one gesture will not be recognized until the other fails.